# Chrome Extensions - html not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, I'm trying to run a jQuery content script in a Chrome Extension. Simple enough, right? I can do:

`$("#header").hide();`

Just fine (if an element has the id "header"), but as soon as I try:

`$(html).hide();`

The console says:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined`

I tried `body`, `div`, everything. I cannot directly grab all elements. What gives?
I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`html` isn't defined, `"html"` is. Put it in quotes.

```
$("html").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM object for `<html>` is `document`, not `html`.